# PHP sql multiple attributes

Tags: php, mysql

I have the folowing query that shows my products.

```
SELECT DISTINCT productsmap.id, attributes_product.waarde, 
attributes_product.att_id, productsmap.name, productsmap.category 
AS categoryId, brand.naam AS brand, productsmap.sku, categorie.name AS 
category, productsmap.price, productsmap.shops

FROM productsmap
INNER JOIN categorie ON productsmap.category = categorie.id
INNER JOIN brand ON productsmap.brand = brand.id
INNER JOIN attributes_product ON productsmap.id = attributes_product.pmapid

WHERE productsmap.category
IN ( 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ) 
AND productsmap.shops >0
AND (
productsmap.price >= 3.94
AND productsmap.price <= 204.99
)
AND productsmap.online =1
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

It gives the folowing results I cropped a bit:

```
(id) (waarde) (att_id) (name) (categoryId) (brand) (sku) 
 2     109        1     Name       4        Merk   70000  
 2     2013       2     Name etc etc etc 
 2     123        3     Name etc etc etc 
 3     103        1     Name2  etc etc 
 3     2012       2     Name2
 3     123        3     Name2
 4     110        1     3name
 4     2013       2     3name
 4     102        3     3name
```

Whit multiple times the same id and name only diffrent att_id and waarde. But i need to add to my query (attributes_product.att_id = 1 and waarde = 109) and (attributes_product.att_id = 2 and waarde = 2013)

But this is not possible because it are diffrent results. How can I solve this issue? Or on what can i search to solve this issue?

It attributes.product are att_id and waarde

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "But this is not possible because it are diffrent results."  can you clarify your question a bit?

Comment: As I see it the first and second row are the same result exept that waarde and att_id is diffrent. and I need to also search on that one.

Comment: What do you mean by "also search"?  Do you mean add it to your WHERE clause?  If that is the case, just add it like `AND waarde = 109`. It might help if you show a sample of the result you are trying to get.

Comment: yes I understand that and i did that but i need to have both 109 and 2013.

Comment: So then put `AND waarde IN (109, 2013)`.

Comment: then i get 0 zero results because per row it is not 109 and 2013

Comment: `IN()` is like saying "either" the value for `waarde` needs to be either 109 or 2013. It doesn't need to be both. Again, it is not really clear what exactly you are asking in terms of what result you seek.